# Cannot Import Clipboard

Tags: react-native

Clipboard seems to be a pretty standard part of react-native's API. All of the tutorials on react-native's Clipboard tell me the same thing, just do this:

```
import { Clipboard } from 'react-native';
```

and I'm golden. Problem is, I'm getting complaints from my IDE that I:

```
Cannot import Clipboard because there is no Clipboard export in react-native
```

I'm very confused at this point and it doesn't seem that anyone else through a quick google search of my error msesage has ever had this problem before. I don't even know how to even begin debugging this. Or if even needs debugging as the code seems to work perfectly fine despite the complaints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Clipboard module was moved to `react-native-community/react-native-clipboard`.

You can install it with:

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/react-native-clipboard
```

and import it with:

```
import Clipboard from "@react-native-community/react-native-clipboard";
```

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-clipboard#migrating-from-the-core-react-native-module)

Comment: Oh, I see. Is is possible to get the setString() functionality without installing that new dependency? I'd rather not have everyone else in my team install a new dependency just for this small feature we're adding.


My secondary question is why my code still worked as expected, even though the import was completely borked.

Comment: @user2019645 when all your team mates are working with the same react-native version as you, how it should be, then of course all your team mates have to install the new dependency, but that's not a big deal and shouldn't be a big problem.